# .jar export does not understand relative paths within project folder

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, relative-path

I have a java project for which I have used Intellij Idea. The project runs fine, and I have exported it as a jar. The jar export also runs properly, *except* for one issue:

I have an additional "resources" folder within my project, and there are two csv files (very simple structure with two columns). In the code, I have used their relative paths as follows

```
private static final __MY_FILE = new File("resources/filename.csv");
```

As expected, this works properly when I run from the IDE. But when I export the project as a jar, the code crashes with `FileNotFoundException` because these relative paths are no longer treated as being relative to project folder.

Temporarily, I have resorted to providing the full path in the code (i.e. `__MY_FILE = new File("/home/.../resources/filename.csv")`), but this is clearly a disastrous practice!

How can I use paths relative to the project folder so that the exported .jar works?

The directory structure is as follows:

```
networkmeasurements
    /matrixmethods
        /src
    /probabilisticmethods
        /src
    /utils
        /src
    /resources
        filename.csv
```

I am trying to get the resource `filename.csv` from a class inside `matrixmethods`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use File, since this file does not exist independently on the file system. Instead you need getResourceAsStream(), for example

```
...
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/filename.csv");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
...
```

Comment: I, too, thought this would work. I had tried getResource() earlier, but the `java.net.URL` object was always null. Also, I tried both "resources/filename.csv" and "/resources/filename.csv". Both return null.

Comment: Saw something I didn't expect: I moved `filename.csv` to the src folder, and `getResource("filename.csv")` worked. BUT ... `getResource("../src/filename.csv")` was null. Same filename and location, same classpaths, but I can't seem to go up one level in the directory structure.

Comment: @ChthonicProject, can you provide the directory structure of your project and where your csv file resides?

Comment: added the folder structure.

Comment: @ChthonicProject, can you confirm that inside your jar, the filename.csv file resides under the "resources" folder?

Comment: Yes, it is under 'resources' folder.

Comment: @ChthonicProject, are you using getClass().getClassLoader().getResource() or getClass().getResource() ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44373/discussion-between-chthonic-project-and-sasankad)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/resource-files.html might have good insight. You have to get Intellij to recognise .csv files as property files so it will bundle them.